# dbt backfill of arbitrary dates

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, dbt

I have processes that periodically pulls time series data from third-party data sources. At times, these data sources may not provide the full insights as I need them or may omit insights for certain objects. When that's the case, it is expected I will need to refetch those insights some other day when I know the data is made available and replace them in my datastore.

I'm new to dbt and use it to handle transformations and aggregation on this data and works fine as is, however when the above scenario occurs, I find myself needing to fully rebuild my models to account for the updated data in my datastore when in reality all I need to rebuild are some specific dates. This model is incremental but this kind of rebuild strategy seems to only allow to reduce the scope of the query to new records with possibly a lookback window, but what I'd really want to be able to run is something like

```
dbt run -s mymodel --from-date=YYYY-MM-DD --to-date=YYYY-MM-DD
```

i.e. something that allows building an arbitrary date window

**Is there a way to run backfills over arbitrary dates in dbt?**

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you don't have a way to identify when the data in the 3rd party system has been updated. Normally, I have my data ingestions record a timestamp of when the ingestion occurred and store that in a field like `SRC_SYNCED_AT`. This is not necessarily the same timestamp as like an `UPDATED_AT` timestamp from the source system. This is your own timestamp that is recorded when the data is transported over. Then I base all of my incremental models off that timestamp. This way, it doesn't matter if the record you're processing was updated in the source system an hour ago or 100 days ago.

But you may not be able to do this if, for example, you have to do a full copy of the 3rd party source data. So, if you can't do it this way, you can create your own solution similar to the `dbt run` command you posted in your question.

First off, hopefully the clauses you need for your incremental models are already in a macro. I use something like this:

```
{%- macro add_basic_incremental_filter(target_table=this, src_time_column='SRC_SYNCED_AT', dest_time_column='SRC_SYNCED_AT', lookback_hours=var('incremental_lookback_hours', 0)) -%}
  {% set start_timestamp = var('start_timestamp', false) %}
  {% if start_timestamp  %}
    {% set end_timestamp = var('end_timestamp', false) %}
    {{ src_time_column }} >= TO_TIMESTAMP({{ start_timestamp }})
    {% if end_timestamp  %}
     AND {{ src_time_column }} <= TO_TIMESTAMP({{ end_timestamp }})
    {% endif %}
  {% elif is_incremental() %}
    {{ src_time_column }} > ({{ get_incremental_lookback_start_time(target_table, dest_time_column, lookback_hours) }})
  {%- else -%}
    TRUE
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}

{%- macro get_incremental_lookback_start_time(target_table, time_column, lookback_hours=0) -%}
  {%- if is_incremental() -%}
    SELECT DATEADD('hour', -{{ lookback_hours }}, MAX({{ time_column }})) FROM {{ target_table }}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

My incremental models will start like this:

```
{{
  config({
    "materialized": 'incremental',
    "unique_key": 'my_key',
  })
}}

WITH MY_MODEL AS (
    SELECT * FROM {{ ref('some_other_model') }}
    WHERE {{ add_basic_incremental_filter() }}
)
```

Now, when I want to run for specific dates, all I have to do is

```
dbt run -s my_model --vars '{"start_timestamp": "2023-03-01", "end_timestamp": "2023-03-15"}'
```

Comment: hey this is very clever! it requires a bit of setup on the models that will need this ability instead of being something available out of the box, but it's a great workaround! going to try this out, thanks so much!!